# How to get Rails and all requirements running to use React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Iam a novice in rails and trying to write my first React frontend. I have read enough to know that there are different methods to use React with rails. I decided to split frontend and backend, and use rails in API mode. I cannot find good sources explaining what I need on my server to get rails and react going, and why. I read so far about npm, node.js, Heroku and so on, but i lack the knowledge to decide what to pick and i dont understand the interactions yet.
Does someone know a good tutorial, some sources or keywords to point me to a direction?

Comment: Might want to take a look at [`hyperstack`](https://hyperstack.org/) as well. Very cool `rails` => `react` platform which uses opal to allow you to build the whole app in ruby code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Rails just in API mode with React on frontend then you can separate those apps completely.

I.e. use Rails/Puma server for API and have a separate server (Nginx/Apache/Node.js) to serve the frontend React app and other static assets.

Answer (score 0):

For using `react` as your `client-side` application and `rails` for the `server-side` you need two different applications. As Rails is `MVC` I suggest you use just `ruby` and `Sinatra` server.
In this situation be careful about the `cross-origin errors` you have to enable it while using two `agents`.
Take a look at [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-rails-project-with-a-react-and-redux-front-end-8b01e17a1db/).